# Проблема с чтением переменных из другого класса

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Читаю константы из другого класса, примерно так:
Переменная в другом классе: `public static const Blocks:Array = ["block1","block2"];`
Читаю так: `Blocks = Level1.Blocks;`

Проблема в том, что по ходу работы нужно модифицировать прочитанный Blocks, и при нажатии на кнопку нужно снова прочитать исходные значения из другого класса, но когда я это делаю, я получаю те же значения, что и в данный момент находятся в массиве Blocks. Иначе говоря, когда я модифицирую Blocks в основном классе, переменная Blocks в классе Level1 тоже меняет свое значение. Можно ли это как-то избежать? Мне и нужен второй класс для того, чтобы из него обновлять переменные до начальных значений.

Объясняю на примере:
Другой класс
    package Levels 
{

```
public class Level1 
{
    public static const Blocks:Array = ["block1","block2"];

    public static const finishX:int = 0;
    public static const finishY:int = 0;

}
```

}

Читаю другим классом и изменяю по ходу работы

```
Blocks = Level1.Blocks;
...
Blocks[0] = "Block100";
Далее
trace(Blocks[0]);
Хочу вернуть на старотовые значения которые хранятся в классе Level1 но
trace(Level1.Blocks[0]);
Выдаст Block100
```

Comment: Прочитал три раза, ничего не понял, перефразируйте пожалуйста!

static - переменная всегда одна при ссылке на нее, "Показывает, что переменная, константа или метод принадлежит классу, а не экземплярам класса".

const - константа, значение или ссылка только для чтения, задается при инициализации класса. "Задает константу, являющуюся переменной, значение которой можно присвоить только один раз".

Comment: Читаю константу из другого класса. Сохраняю ее в другой переменной в другом классе. А когда эту переменную модифицирую, меняется и значение константы др.класса если ее заного прочесть.

Comment: потому что меняются переменные внутри массива 

используйте метод, например с геттером (только для чтения)

       public function get getConstValues():Array
       {
           return ["val1","val2"];
       }

Comment: Все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сама ссылка на массив константа, переменные внутри него неконстанты

```
        private const ARR:Array = ["1","1"];

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            ARR[0] = 2;
            trace(ARR[0]); // 2

            ARR = []; // Error !!!
        }
```

Comment: Дополнил свой пост